# Get-ADUser Filter parameter matching second time around

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm going to have to explain this step by step. First, here's some code that I'm trying to get working:

```
$Users = Get-Content c:\textfile.txt
foreach ($user in $users) {Get-ADuser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -like "$user*"}}
```

So when I run this, it returns nothing, which I know is wrong. So I used break points to look a little closer. I found that the variable *$user* is indeed populating with the correct values. As a test, I replaced *$user* in the filter with one value (so that it looks like code below) from the text file and stepped through it.

```
$Users = Get-Content c:\textfile.txt
foreach ($user in $users) {Get-ADuser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -like "1234567890*"}}
```

This is where it gets interesting. I put the break point on the foreach line and as I let it run through the first time, nothing wrote to the screen except a blank line. When I stepped through it the second time, output as if the command had run twice came out, i.e. the user object with the user principal name like 1234567890* wrote to the screen twice.

As another clue, I tried the following line:

```
Get-Content c:\textfile.txt | Get-ADuser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -like "$_*" }
```

And it pops out an error saying that the Filter parameter doesn't take pipeline input. I don't know if that means anything, but I suspect it doesn't since I'm not really using the pipeline in my original code. It's probably something super basic with the Get-ADUser cmdlet that I'm not tracking, even though I've been using Powershell for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the filter is a little finicky within AD. It is actually `-filter <string>`

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '$($user)*'"
```

`where-object` is the other type of filter syntax you were attempting to use. E.G. `where-object {UserPrincipalName -like "$user*"}`

Comment: Ya know, I knew about the different ways to format the filter, I just didn't try it. I had always thought using the "{}" were superior for some reason. Any idea on why using the string instead of a set of curly brackets works better for this?

Comment: For any future viewers of this post, there are two different TechNet pages for this cmdlet. One is for the "addsadministration" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#required-parameters

And the other is for the activedirectory module, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps#required-parameters

Comment: As you mentioned, different cmdlets by the look. A `get-help` of the the command shows the string is needed..

Comment: What's also interesting though, is that the TechNet articles I posted above show examples using the {}'s

Comment: After testing some more, looks like it doesn't like inserting the UPN into the filter from pipeline. It works fine if you just do `Get-Content c:\textfile.txt | Get-ADuser` but it tries searching the UPN as the SamAccountName instead, which shows no results. E.G. `Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Test.Account@Contoso.com'`

Comment: Hmmm... Now when I run it with a static value, it works the first time stepping through in debug mode. Crazy. I hadn't even closed Powershell and reopened it or anything.